# Associativity of infinite series

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

In my calculus notes, my professor presented the following proposition:

**Proposition:** Let $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ be a convergent series and let $1=n_1<n_2<n_3<...$ be an increasing sequence of indices. Consider the set of grouped sums of the sequence between these indices, i.e; $$A_k=\sum_{n=n_k}^{n_{k+1}-1}a_n.$$ Then, $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}A_k=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$$

This proposition is supposed to say that if an infinite series converges, then the associative property holds. I was reading an equivalent proposition, but written in a different way, and I was able to prove it. However, I can't prove the statement the way my professor wrote it. Any help is welcome

**Addendum:**
The proposition I was able to prove is **Exercise 2.5.3** (a) on page 65 from the book *Understanding Analysis, 2nd ed* by Stephen Abbott.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $$\sum_{k=1}^N A_k =\sum_{i=1}^{n_{N+1}-1} a_i$$ because finite sums are associative.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to see that the sequence of partial sums of the $A_k$ is Cauchy, so that sequence of partial sums (*i.e.*, the infinite sum) must converge to something.  And since the sequence of partial sums of the $A_k$ is a subsequence of the sequence of partial sums of $a_n$, we know what that something has to be.

Answer (score 1):

May be following view also will be helpful: $\sum\limits_{k=1}^N A_k$ is subsequence of $\sum\limits_{k=1}^N a_k$.